# Codeigniter. How to get sum of database columns

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables .

**pre_order**
[image]

**receive_pre_order**
[image]

My Question is how to get all the information from **pre_order table** and get the **SUM** of all the quantity received form **receive_pre_order table** against that `pre_order id`.
To make it clear suppose we have the following data in **recieve_pre_order** .

```
+--------------+------------+-------------------+
| pre_order_id | product_id | quantity_recieved |
+--------------+------------+-------------------+
|            1 |          1 |                10 | 
|            1 |          1 |                20 | 
|            1 |          1 |                10 |
+--------------+------------+-------------------+
```

It should return `quantity_recieved = 40` against `pre_order_id 1` .

Right now I have tried:

```
$this->db->select_sum('quantity_recieved');
$this->db->from('recieve_pre_order');
return $this->db->get();
```

It is working but, it is getting data from one table.
But I want to fetch data from both tables.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Join the two tables tables (`rpo.pre_order_id = po.id`). Group the result for `po.id`, so all Rows with the same `po.id` will be grouped into one row. `sum(rpo.quantity_recieved)` will sum up the quantity for these groups.

```
select po.id, sum(rpo.quantity_recieved)
from receive_pre_order rpo 
join pre_order po on rpo.pre_order_id = po.id  
group by po.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  $this->db->select("sum(recieve_pre_order.quantity_recieved),pre_order.id");
  $this->db->from('recieve_pre_order');
  $this->db->join("pre_order",'recieve_pre_order.pre_order_id = pre_order.id','left outer');
  $this->db->where('recieve_pre_order.pre_order_id',your parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $this->db->select('pre_order.*');
  $this->db->select_sum('recieve_pre_order.quantity_recieved');
  $this->db->from('pre_order');
  $this->db->join("recieve_pre_order",'recieve_pre_order.pre_order_id = pre_order.id','left');
```

Answer (score 0):

try sub query instead of joining table.

```
  $this->db->select("po.*,SELECT(SUM(quantity_recieved) from receive_pre_order where pre_order_id = po.id) as total_recieved_quantity",FALSE);
  $this->db->from('pre_order as po');
  return $this->db->get();
```